# Can two players use two Trap Masters on the Traptanium Portal that are the same character?

Tags: skylanders

Say my child and I think one particular Trap Master is very good, and we would both like to use that Trap Master on the Traptanium Portal. Therefore, I buy two of the same Trap Master, and each of us place one on the Traptanium Portal so that we can each play as that character. Would this be possible? Does the game allow this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can, and yes it does.  Each character will be a separate entity and will level up independently.

Comment: lol, it's funny, 'cause my daughter actually answered my question last night, without me asking. She said that two people can play as the same Trap Master. And then I told her, "Oh yeah? That would probably be kind of boring though, wouldn't it?" She said, "Yeah." I should have just asked her in the first place. :)